# How can I automate the installation of a custom Android-x86 ISO for testing purposes?

Tags: android, android-x86

Using the docker setup at https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-aosp I have managed to build a custom Android-x86 version that I can run and install on a VirtualBox/QEMU setup.

I am now concerned with speeding up the edit-compile-build-test cycle.

The custom system I am working on is graphical in nature, and so I do need some visual confirmation.

The problem I have is that I cannot figure out how to create a QEMU or VirtualBox image that will take me to the home screen immediately without running through the installation and Google account setup.

I have no problem scripting this, I just don't even know where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are basically attempting to get rid of the Google start-up setup wizard.
This can be achieved by removing the SetupWizared's *Andoird.mk* file from the AOSP source repo, and building a version of your device that will not contain the wizard.
In a GMS (Google Mobile Services) device's repo , go to:
*repo_root/vendor/google/apps/SetupWizard* and delete the *Android.mk* file. This will effectively disable the wizard app and it will not show up the upon booting from a fresh system flash.

Alternatively, If you have root access to the device, you might want to mark the Setup Wizard as completed by invoking the following adb commands:

```
adb shell
adb shell "settings put secure user_setup_complete 1"
adb reboot
```

(Please note that I haven't tested this)

Comment: This worked, although I ultimately decided to simply run the emulator directly after building the AOSP repositories. This seemed to skip the setup wizard.